# Are Chrome 'Other search engines' synced when logged into Google?

Tags: google-chrome, search, google-search

**Are Chrome 'Other search engines' synced across devices when a user is logged into their Google account?**

*See:* [chrome://settings/searchEngines](http://chrome://settings/searchEngines) > *Other search engines*

[image]

Exploring the data that is currently synced by Chrome, it does not mention search engines.

*See:* [chrome.google.com/sync](https://chrome.google.com/sync?hl=en-US)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 'Other search engines' appear to be synced across devices when a user is logged into their Google account.

This may be tested by creating a new user on the computer, and logging into the Chrome browser on a newly downloaded instance of Chrome.